# AutoIt WinHttp.au3 dependencies can't be found

Tags: http, autoit

I'm trying to use an AutoIt script I found. After installing AutoIt v3.3.14.2 when I try to run it can't find the module WinHttp.au3.

So I looked for it and placed it in the same folder as the script. But now WinHttp.au3 has an include file which doesn't exist either, which is WinHttpConstants.au3 and so on.

Which version or package of AutoIt do I have to install so the script that includes WinHttp.au3 has all the dependencies it needs to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AutoIt WinHTTP** is a custom UDF (not included with AutoIt) consisting of `WinHttp.au3` and `WinHttpConstants.au3` (being its only dependency).

- AutoIt WinHTTP [releases](https://github.com/dragana-r/autoit-winhttp/releases)
- AutoIt WinHTTP [support](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/84133-winhttp-functions/)